# How to add Twitter-Bootstrap class to Symfony Form Input?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have got form like that: One input field - Text with name `trollName`.

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class myFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('trollName','text')
        ;
    }
}
```

Some controller:

```
$myForm = $this->createForm(new myFormType()) -> createView();
```

I want to render this field, but I want to use bootstrap class - `form-control`

How to modify twig view:

```
{{ form_widget(myForm.trollName) }}
```

... to get response like that:

```
<input type='text' name='trollName' class='form-control'> <!-- form-control class is from boostrap -->
```

Comment: [See the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are strating a new project I will suggest you to use Symfony 2.6 which includes Twitter bootstrap.

Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) for more details

Answer (score 0):

For SF version < 2.6, you can do it like this:

example:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal style-form', 'role': 'form'}}) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.trollName, 'TrollName', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-2 control-label'}}) }}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.trollName, {'attr': {'class':'form-control'}}) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.trollName) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
            {{ form_widget(form.submit, {'attr': {'class':'btn btn-theme'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```